# Formatting strings into dates in mySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, ms-access

I am migrating an Access db to mySQL.  I am receiving the tables as CSVs and using Excel to drop and format some columns.  The dates are coming to me as m/d/yyyy and go as far back as 1702.  Since Excel brilliantly won't format any date before 1900 I am going to have to transform them some other way.  Now it would be super simple to write a PHP script to iterate over rows and use `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))` but I was wondering if there was a function or functions in mySQL that would be the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. e.g.

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('4/1/1960', '%m/%d/%Y');